# How to start a background process in macosx?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to start a background process in macosx, but am not sure how to do it in cocoa.
Can you please suggest

Answer (score 1):

See [Task Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OperatingSystem/Concepts/task.html) in *Interacting with the Operating System*. You generally want to use `NSTask` for this.

Also look at [Manipulating Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Workspace/Articles/ManipulatingApplications.html) in *Workspace Service Programming Guide* if you don't need to communicated with the background process.

Comment: thanks for the response, but I am looking for a background process not a thread

Comment: Correct. The above are how to launch background processes, not threads.